# How does a 'const struct' differ from a 'struct'?

Tags: c, syntax

What does `const struct` mean? Is it different from `struct`?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

The `const` part really applies to the variable, not the structure itself.

e.g. @Andreas correctly says:

```
const struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} foo = {10, 20};
foo.x = 5; //Error
```

But the important thing is that variable `foo` is constant, not the `struct` definition itself. 
You could equally write that as:

```
struct apoint {
    int x;
    int y;
};

const struct apoint foo = {10, 20};
foo.x = 5; // Error

struct apoint bar = {10, 20};
bar.x = 5; // Okay
```

Answer (score 27):

It means the `struct` is constant i.e. you can't edit it's fields after it's been initialized.

```
const struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} foo = {10, 20};
foo.x = 5; //Error
```

**EDIT:** GrahamS correctly points out that the constness is a property of the variable, in this case `foo`, and not the struct definition:

```
struct Foo {
    int x;
    int y;
};
const struct Foo foo = {10, 20};
foo.x = 5; //Error
struct Foo baz = {10, 20};
baz.x = 5; //Ok
```

Comment: Cheers. Can I get a +1 for my observation? :D

Answer (score 0):

'const' as the word constant itself indicates means unmodifiable. This can be applied to variable of any data type. struct being a user defined data type, it applies to the the variables of any struct as well. Once initialized, the value of the const variables cannot be modified.

Answer (score -1):

Const means you **cannot edit** the field of the structure after the declaration and initialization and you **can** retrieve the data form the structure

Answer (score -6):

you can not modify a constant struct ,first struct is a simple data type so when a const key word comes on ,the compiler will held a memory space on a register rather than temporary storage(like ram),and variable identifiers that is stored on register can not be modified

Comment: This is incorrect. The struct is not stored in a register.